# Rails command not found when i launch it in new tab in console, but if i go out of that directory and come back in rails command work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails command not found when i launch it in a new tab in console, but if i go out of that directory and come back, rails command works.

**Console output.**

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.13 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.13
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.8.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.8.0
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6
Ignoring concurrent-ruby-ext-1.0.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine concurrent-ruby-ext --version 1.0.5
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.3
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.0
Ignoring ffi-1.11.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.11.1
Ignoring ffi-1.9.14 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.14 
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Ignoring mysql2-0.3.11 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.11
Ignoring nokogiri-1.9.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.9.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.8.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.8.1
Ignoring rmagick-2.13.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine rmagick --version 2.13.2
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.6
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.4
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: By any chance are you using a ruby version switcher such as rbenv?

Comment: Trying to remove ruby and rails and install them with rvm , Check this link 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I was able to fix my issue. It turned out in bash profile the path wasn't set properly. In my case issue was ordering inside the bash profile, had to add the line at the end.